# Rcpp: how to pass "NULL" to a "NumericMatrix" in a rcpp function

Tags: r, null, rcpp

I have an argument in a Rcpp function called `X_mat`, which is a `NumericMatrix` by default, which means that the user should pass a matrix to `X_mat`. But I'd like to have a `ifelse` statement based on the actual input of `X_mat`, such as

```
cppFunction('double getsum(NumericMatrix X_mat) {
if(X_mat == NULL ){
  sum = 1;
}else{
  sum = X_mat(1,1);
}
   return sum;
}')
```

I'd like to allow the user to use `NULL` for X matrix but this will cause an error. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: We have `Rcpp::Nullable<>` for that reason, and a few answers already here and on the Rcpp Gallery.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! But now `.ncol()` and `.nrow()` couldn't be applied to a ``Nullable`` variable. Could you please tell me what to use to get the row and column sizes? Thanks!